# What selector should i use to prepend element to body of iframe with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add an element to the body of an iframe using jquery.

```
$('iframe body').prepend('<div id="shader" />');
```

It doesnt work. It seems to have to do with the selector?

Comment: Are you missing a .contents() there?

Comment: `$("body iframe").content().prepend("<div id="shader" />")`

Comment: Seems that your appending the div element to the iframe tag and not to the content inside the iframe

Comment: @JanDvorak The difference from that question, as far as I can understand, is that in that solution, as far as i can understand, the DOM of the iFrame gets emptied

Comment: For anybody reading this: The proposed duplicate is invalid. here is the correct solution: $("#wrapper").contents().find('body')